# Two DNS Names for two Web apps in jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a problem. I have two web apps deployed as wars. Let's call them app1.war and app2.war.

I would like app1.war to be accessed at the URL www.website.com and I would like app2.war to be accessible as www.anotherweb.com. I have my domain name ready.

I am able to run the application as www.website.com/app1, www.website.com/app2.

So Now i need to run using www.website.com and www.anotherweb.com

I am running JBoss7.1.1.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put [Apache Http server](http://httpd.apache.org/) between user and JBoss server and not access your server directly from web. Configure Apache HTTP server to use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) with [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) configuration. If your JBoss server runs on `http://localhost:8080`, it will look something like this in `httpd.conf`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    ServerName www.website.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    ServerName www.anotherweb.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't have an Apache web server I need to do all in the Jboss application server