# unable to access with domain name jboss server having two instance in one machine

Tags: apache, jboss

we are using jbossEAP 6.0 , we have two instances of jboss server in one machine .Both jboss server have same application.

We are unable to access jboss server from different domain . 
Suppose user  type **example.com**  then  it should redirect to **localhost:8080** and in the case of **demo.com,  **localhost:8084**. For this we configure in apache 2.0 but it always hitting first configuration available in **httpd.conf**.

So please suggest me to solve this issue .The httpd configuration is like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias example.com
      ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8010/    
       ProxyPassReverse /foo http://example.com/
       RewriteEngine On    
       RewriteRule ^/$ /foo/ [R]
       ErrorLog logs/example-error_log
       CustomLog logs/example-access_log combined
       JkMount /foo/* foo
  </VirtualHost>





        <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName www.demo.com
            ServerAlias demo.com
            ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/    
            ProxyPassReverse /foo http://demo.com/foo
            RewriteEngine On    
            RewriteRule ^/$ /foo/ [R]

            ErrorLog logs/demo-error_log
              CustomLog logs/demo-access_log combined
           JkMount /foo/* foo
       </VirtualHost>
```

we are not changing any file of jboss server for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line before defining virtual hosts?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Here is ho I configured it, but didn't used mod_jk.

[Two DNS Names for two Web apps in jboss 7.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472963/two-dns-names-for-two-web-apps-in-jboss-7-1-1/20581558#20581558)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but in my case,I have two different jboss server with different port number.

Comment: both jboss server running in same machine